# Send data between threads and pool in python

Tags: python, python-3.x, multithreading, multiprocessing, threadpool

I have function A that runs in parallel with various arguments. And there are 2 threads. I would like to send data from function A to function B. If possible, send this data before random10 is executed.

```
from multiprocessing import Pool
from threading import Thread
import time
import random

def a(avalue):
    while True:
        random1 = random.randint(0,9)
#       return random1
        random10 = random.randint(0, 9)
        time.sleep(0.1)

def b():
    while True:
#       print (a(avalue) + a(avalue))
        time.sleep(0.1)

def run_in_parallel():
    valuelist = [0,1]
    pool = Pool(processes=len(valuelist))
    pool.map(a, valuelist)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    Thread(target = b).start()
    Thread(target = run_in_parallel()).start()
```

How can this be done? Thanks

Comment: have you looked at `multiprocessing.Queue`?

Comment: Yep! What you're looking for is called "inter-process communication", or IPC. The `multiprocessing` module has lots of good stuff for that. As Rufus stated, `Queue` is particularly good here.